# AWS SDK for iOS Regions and Endpoints

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am testing Amazon's SimpleDB and downloaded the SDK for IOS

Got a bit frustrated that it doesn't say where to change the endpoint.

The default endpoint is sdb.amazonaws.com
but I would like to change to sdb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

Does anyone know where I can change this?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution on this page:
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/CloudFront/3912

In AmazonClientManager.m

```
    sdb = [[AmazonSimpleDBClient alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY]; // existing code 

    sdb.endpoint = @"http://sdb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"; // add new line to set the endpoint
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use one of the predefined constants rather than specifying the endpoint via string:

```
sdb = [[AmazonSimpleDBClient alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
sdb.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints sdbEndpoint:AP_SOUTHEAST_1];
```